# How to handle Animation Timing with state in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Im trying to increase the height of my View when pressing TouchableOpacity component, but it's not working. what did i do wrong ? should i use a lifeCycle component ?

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  View
} from "react-native";
import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";

const Screen_Height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

class RegistrationView extends React.Component {
  state = {
    registrationHeight: new Animated.Value(150),
  };

  increaseHeight = () => {
      Animated.timing(this.state.registrationHeight, {
      toValue: Screen_Height,
      duration: 500
    }).start();
  };

 render() {
    return (
<Animated.View
            style={{
              height: this.state.registrationHeight
            }}
          >
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.increaseHeight()}>
              <View>
                <Text>
                  Welcome, press here.
                </Text>
              </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
 </Animated.View>
)
}
```

i get this Error:

> ** TypeError: config.easing is not a function.(In 'config.easing((0,base.divide)(newFrameTime, config.duration))', 'config.easing' is undefined) **

Comment: Please, add code of the View component where `this.state.registrationHeight` is used. (Wild guess, you're using _View_ instead of _Animated.View_)

Answer (score 7):

Solve, The problem was on the import module , i should do : ** import { Animated } from "react-native" **; not : ** import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";**

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about the view of your TouchableOpacity, try to replace this part of your code:

```
<View>
  <Text>
    Welcome, press here.
  </Text>
</View>
```

with this:

```
<Animated.View style={{height: this.state.registrationHeight}}>
  <Text>
     Welcome, press here.
  </Text>
</Animated.View>
```